# How do I make a kind of textbox to write content?

Tags: html, css

I am not familiar with CSS styling but I want to make a textbox for user to write content on it. Like an email content where you can write your message. Here is a screenshot of my content.

[image]

As you can see I can only write my text in the middle of the "box". Is it possible to be able to give flexibility to write anywhere I point my mouse cursor at like a normal email content?

My code:

```
To:<input type="text" style="font-size: 10pt;" size="30" name="Recipient"  ><br><br>

Subject:<input type="text" style="font-size: 10pt" size="70" name="Subject" ><br><br>


    Content:<input type="text" style="height: 400px;font-size: 10pt; width: 800px;" name="Content" height="100px" width="100px" ><br><br>
```

I don't know if textbox is a good idea for this. Because when the text fills up at the end of the box, it keeps going right but I want the text to go to the next line.

Comment: What you need is a [textarea element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) not an input element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `<textArea>`

```html
<label>
    Content:
    <br>
    <textarea cols="60"  rows="20" name="content"></textarea>
</label>
```

Just adjust the `cols` and `rows` properties and add the style you want.

Comment: is label tag neccessary?

Comment: no! see doc:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: You don't have to use it, you can read about it here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20081103/H44